# Converting GAS macros into MASM macros

Tags: assembly, macros, masm, gnu-assembler

I am studying a Forth compiler, [JonesForth](https://github.com/AlexandreAbreu/jonesforth/blob/master/jonesforth.S) which is written for Linux in [GAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler). My plan is to rewrite it, with a few small changes in [MASM32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler), as a way to improve my understanding of the internal mechanics of Forth and relearn assembly programming (I last used assembly on a [6509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6509) processor in the early 1980s).

I'm OK with assembly code itself, and I *think* I understand what the GAS macros actually *do*. But I am having difficulty converting them to MASM macros (probably because I am still a bit sketchy on MASM macros).

Here is what Jones writes (with my comments added in square brackets):

[link ard DOCOL are pre-defined ...]

BUILT-IN WORDS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

Remember our dictionary entries (headers)? Let's bring those together with the codeword and data words to see how: DOUBLE DUP + ; really looks in memory.

```
  pointer to previous word
   ^
   |
+--|------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| LINK    | 6 | D | O | U | B | L | E | 0 | DOCOL      | DUP        | +          | EXIT       |
+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------------+--|---------+------------+------------+
       ^       len                         pad  codeword      |
   |                              V
  LINK in next word                Points to codeword of DUP
```

Initially we can't just write ": DOUBLE DUP + ;" (i.e. that literal string) here, because we don't yet have anything to read the string, break it up at spaces, parse each word, etc., etc. So instead we will have to define built-in words using the GNU assembler data constructors (like .int, .byte, .string, .ascii and so on -- look them up in the GAS info page if you are unsure of them).

The long way would be:

```
    .int <link to previous word>
    .byte 6          // Length
    .ascii "DOUBLE"  // String
    .byte 0          // Padding
 DOUBLE: .int DOCOL  // Codeword
    .int DUP         // Pointer to codeword of DUP
    .int PLUS        // Pointer to codeword of +
    .int EXIT        // Pointer to codeword of EXIT
```

That's going to get quite tedious rather quickly, so here I define an assembler macro so that I can just write:

```
defword "DOUBLE",6,,DOUBLE
.int DUP,PLUS,EXIT
```

and I'll get exactly the same effect.

Don't worry too much about the exact implementation details of this macro - it's complicated!

```
    .macro defword name, namelen, flags=0, label
    .section .rodata
    .align 4
    .globl name_\label
name_\label :
    .int link              // Link
    .set link,name_\label
    .byte \flags+\namelen  // Flags + length byte
    .ascii "\name"         // The name
    .align 4               // Padding to next 4 byte boundary
    .globl \label
\label :
    .int DOCOL             // Codeword - the interpreter
    // List of word pointers follow
    .endm
```

Similarly I want a way to write words written in assembly language. There will quite a few
of these to start with because, well, everything has to start in assembly before there's
enough "infrastructure" to be able to start writing Forth words, but also I want to define
some common Forth words in assembly language for speed, even though I could write them in Forth.

This is what DUP looks like in memory:

```
  Pointer to previous word
   ^
   |
+--|------+---+---+---+---+------------+
| LINK    | 3 | D | U | P | code_DUP ---------------------> Points to the assembly
+---------+---+---+---+---+------------+                    code used to write DUP,
       ^       Len              Codeword                    which ends with NEXT.
   |
  LINK in next word
```

Again, for brevity in writing the header I'm going to write an assembler macro called defcode. As with defword above, don't worry about the complicated details of the macro.

```
    .macro defcode name, namelen, flags=0, label
    .section .rodata
    .align 4
    .globl name_\label
name_\label :
    .int link             // Link
    .set link,name_\label
    .byte \flags+\namelen // Flags + length byte
    .ascii "\name"        // The name
    .align 4              // Padding to next 4 byte boundary
    .globl \label
\label :
    .int code_\label      // Codeword
    .text
    .globl code_\label
code_\label :             // Assembler code follows
    .endm
```

[Examples...(TCFA, INCR4, and EXIT are pre-defined address labels, NEXT is a pre-defined MACRO)]

```
    defword ">DFA",4,,TDFA
    .int TCFA        // >CFA       (Get code field address)
    .int INCR4        // 4+        (Add 4 to it to get to next word)
    .int EXIT        // EXIT       (Return from FORTH word)


    defcode "DROP",4,,DROP
    pop %eax        // Drop top of stack
    NEXT
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to leave it in GAS assembly?

Comment: @Ross Ridge That would defeat the point a bit - I have been learning MASM and want to keep it that way.

Comment: If that's the point then having someone else translate the macros for you would also be a defeat.

Comment: @Ross Ridge Ross, I am not asking anyone to "provide" the macros for me - In fact I would prefer to write them myself. However it is often the case when trying to learn something new that you need some guidance to cross a particular obstacle. That is why I asked for help rather than a translation.

Comment: @Ross Ridge Then if you are _capable_ of translating the macros and _willing_ to provide help, I would be grateful for the assistance. I am sure I could _learn_ from the translation...